# Вывести данные из двух таблиц в одну строку с суммированием значений и разбиением по дням

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть две таблицы. В одной начисления, в другой списания баланса. Нужно в одну строку вывести значения из обеих таблиц для заданного пользователя в определенном интервале. За определенный интервал в одной таблице могут быть значения, а в другой может не быть. Во второй таблице нужно сложить списания за день. И выводить даты.
Важно не суммировать значения в первой таблице. Поскольку зачисления могут быть их разных источников, а списание всегда из одного.

Может быть и так, что нет ни начислений, ни списаний за день. Тогда вывести пустую строку с датой. Если это вообще возможно.

Возможно ли это вообще сделать на чистом sql или нужно будет обрабатывать програмно и собирать нужный массив?

Пример первой таблицы:

| Логин | Сумма | Комментарий | Дата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user | 500 | Зачисление | 2022-08-24 |
| user | 7000 | Зачисление №2 | 2022-08-25 |
| user | 1000 | Зачисление | 2022-08-25 |

Вторая таблица

| Логин | Сумма | Комментарий | Дата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user | -10 | Списание | 2022-08-24 |
| user | -20 | Списание | 2022-08-24 |
| user | -30 | Списание | 2022-08-24 |
| user | -100 | Списание | 2022-08-26 |
| user | -200 | Списание | 2022-08-26 |
| user | -300 | Списание | 2022-08-26 |

Результат

| Логин | Зачисление | Списание | Дата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user | 500 | -60 | 2022-08-24 |
| user | 700 | -60 | 2022-08-24 |
| user | 1000 | null | 2022-08-25 |
| user | null | -600 | 2022-08-26 |

Comment: Скорректируйте, пожалуйста, данные. Сейчас нестыковка, в первой таблице зачисление 7000 за 25ое, но в результирующей этого нет, и откуда-то берется зачисление 700 за 24ое

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это то, что вам нужно:

```
select b.login,t1.summa as zachislenie,sum(distinct t2.summa) as spisanie,b.data
    from (
      select distinct login,data from (
        SELECT distinct login,data from table1
        union all
        SELECT distinct login,data from table2
      ) a
    ) b left join table1 t1 on b.data=t1.data left join table2 t2
    on b.data=t2.data group by b.login,b.data,t1.summa
```

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL нет FULL JOIN-ов, поэтому вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE income (login VARCHAR(255), amount REAL, note VARCHAR(255), ddate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO income (login, amount, note, ddate) VALUES
('user', 500, 'Зачисление', '2022-08-24'),
('user', 7000, 'Зачисление №2', '2022-08-25'),
('user', 1000, 'Зачисление', '2022-08-25');

CREATE TABLE outcome (login VARCHAR(255), amount REAL, note VARCHAR(255), ddate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO outcome (login, amount, note, ddate) VALUES
('user', -10, 'Списание', '2022-08-24'),
('user', -20, 'Списание', '2022-08-24'),
('user', -30, 'Списание', '2022-08-24'),
('user', -100, 'Списание', '2022-08-26'),
('user', -200, 'Списание', '2022-08-26'),
('user', -300, 'Списание', '2022-08-26');

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN i.login IS NULL THEN o.login ELSE i.login END AS login,
    SUM(i.amount) AS amount_i,
    SUM(o.amount) AS amount_o,
    CASE WHEN i.ddate IS NULL THEN o.ddate ELSE i.ddate END AS ddate
FROM income i
    LEFT JOIN outcome o ON o.ddate = i.ddate
GROUP BY i.login, o.login, i.ddate, o.ddate
UNION 
SELECT
    CASE WHEN i.login IS NULL THEN o.login ELSE i.login END AS login,
    SUM(i.amount) AS amount_i,
    SUM(o.amount) AS amount_o,
    CASE WHEN i.ddate IS NULL THEN o.ddate ELSE i.ddate END AS ddate
FROM income i
    RIGHT JOIN outcome o ON o.ddate = i.ddate
GROUP BY i.login, o.login, i.ddate, o.ddate;
    
DROP TABLE income;   
DROP TABLE outcome;
```